# MySQL Stored Procedure with multiple optional parameters

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

i am trying to make a stored procedure that has multiple optionals parameters, i have tried with IF statement but i can't make it work and this is the last code i have tried.

I want to filter by "Usuario" if it is not null 
I'm giving "Usuario" as an example, but it will have others filters like it.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`conciliacion`@`%` PROCEDURE `BuscarRRNormal`(IN `FechaDesde` DATE, IN `FechaHasta` DATE, IN `Usuario` varchar(255))
BEGIN

SELECT IDS, Fecha_Recarga, Usuario, Monto, Operador
FROM transaccionesrr
WHERE (Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN FechaDesde AND FechaHasta) 
AND (@Usuario IS NULL OR Usuario = @Usuario);

END
```

It's seems like mySQL doesn't support optional parameters but there could be a similar option?. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the variable `@Usario` is not the same object as the procedure IN parameter `Usario`. They are different variables. You cannot reference `@Usario` to get the value of the IN parameter `Usario`.

You should name your parameter something distinct from the column name you want to compare it to, then just use it in the query without a `@` character. For example, one could use a naming convention to prefix the parameter names with "p".

```
CREATE DEFINER=`conciliacion`@`%` PROCEDURE `BuscarRRNormal`(IN `pFechaDesde` DATE, IN `pFechaHasta` DATE, IN `pUsuario` varchar(255))
BEGIN

SELECT IDS, Fecha_Recarga, Usuario, Monto, Operador
FROM transaccionesrr
WHERE (Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN pFechaDesde AND pFechaHasta) 
AND (pUsuario IS NULL OR Usuario = pUsuario);

END
```

Comment: it's working pretty well, thank you.
I just needed to send a Null value to "pUsuario"  so it doesn't filter by Usuario.